# Difficulty determining the number of irreducible factors in factorization of $x^{127} - 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am having difficulty determining the number of irreducible factors of $x^{127} - 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I know that all irreducible factors of $1$ and $7$ are divisors of $x^{127} - 1$, since $x^{127} = x^{2^7 - 1}$, and $1, 7$ are the divisors of $7$. This is derived from the theorem that $x^{(p^n)}−x$ is the product of all the irreducible polynomials of degree $d,d \mid n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

I know that there are of course 2 irreducible polynomials of degree $1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which are $x$ and $x + 1$, but I'm unsure about how to determine how many irreducible polynomials of degree $7$ there is (is there an efficient and simple algorithm for doing so)? Furthermore, even I have all the irreducible polynomials of degree $7$, performing long division to find the other divisors of $x^{127} - 1$ is unfeasible to do by hand. Are there any tricks I can use to solve tis problem.

Comment: The number of $7$-degree factors can be determined using properties of cyclotomic polynomials, but I doubt that there is a trick to determine those factors easily by hand.

Comment: If all you want is the number of factors, showing the polynomial is squarefree does it.

Comment: Since 127 is prime, all roots of $x^{127}-1$ in $\mathbb F_{128}$ different from $1$ have multiplicative order $127$ and so generate $\mathbb F_{128}$ as an extension of $\mathbb F_{2}$. Thus, all irreducible factors of $x^{127}-1$ have degree $7$. Write $127 = 1+ 7k$ and get $k=18$.

Comment: @Ihf $k = 18$ is the total number of irreducible factors right? And that means that my original assumption that all linear irreducible polynomials of $x^{127} - 1$ was incorrect, right?

Comment: One factor has degree $1$ ,namely $x-1$. If we divide it out , we get the $127$ th cyclotomic polynomial (since $127$ is prime)

Comment: I think you don't even need to use the fact that 127 is prime.  It should be enough to observe that if $\zeta$ is a root, then $[\mathbb{F}_2(\zeta) : \mathbb{F}_2] \mid [\mathbb{F}_{128} : \mathbb{F}_2] = 7$ and of course if $\zeta \ne 1$ then $[\mathbb{F}_2(\zeta) : \mathbb{F}_2] > 1$.

Comment: Note that 18 is also the number of distinct 7th-degree irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb Z_2$. I suspect this is not a coincidence.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Would you mind explaining what the notation $[\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) : \mathbb{F}_2] \,\, | \,\, [\mathbb{F}_{128} \,\, : \,\, \mathbb{F}_2]$ means and where the $128$ came from?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I doubt that we have the same result for higher degree and/or a higher prime $p$ in $\mathbb Z_p$. I might be wrong however.

Comment: $[\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) : \mathbb{F}_2]$ is the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$; and then the overall statement is giving a divisibility relation between two extension degrees.  And the 128 comes from the fact that each 127th root of 1 is in $\mathbb{F}_{128}$.